# How can I paste the clipboard content from the Android TeamViewer client to the computer running the TeamViewer server that I connected to?

Tags: copy-paste, teamviewer

I use the TeamViewer Android application.

How can I paste the clipboard content from the Android TeamViewer client to the computer running the TeamViewer server that I connected to?

When I press on <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + V</kbd using the Hacker's keyboard when connected to the host, it doesn't retrieve the Android clipboard. Also I didn't see any option in TeamViewer to send the clipboard content.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It should be possible with text, but likely not possible with files/folders if that's what you're after.

Comment: @l3l_aze When I press on <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd using the Hacker's keyboard when connected to the host, it doesn't retrieve the Android clipboard. Also I didn't see any option in TeamViewer to send the clipboard content

Comment: I'm sorry. It looks like it *could* be caused by two options on the host -- one enables `Ctrl + click` as right click, the other is "clipboard synchronization". According to their website both should be available in Settings/Preferences -> Advanced, maybe under the "Extras" tab. I only have 2x Android to test and neither of these is an option, but it does still copy to the client clipboard (using 6.0.1 as client + 8.1.0 as host).